# How to Save Variable to a Dataframe inside a For Loop in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, loops

I have a more complicated code but I just created this simple example to explain what I need to do.

```
for i in np.arange(0,360): 
    r = 2*i
    print(r)
    d = {'r': [r]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

Instead of printing `r`, how would I save `r` into the dataframe `df`? I tried to replicate an example from the documentation for dataframes but I'm lost how to properly add every iteration of `r` to the dataframe.

Comment: It's not clear what you intend, because `df` is a dict, not a data frame.  Regardless of the terminology, you're asking us how to assign to a well-documented data structure -- just what confuses you from the tutorials and examples on your data type?

Comment: I apologize. Please see my edit to the original post.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
You're still confusing the two data structures.  On each loop, you set `d` to a single-element dict, and then convert that to a single-row data frame, overwriting the original data frame.  Please work through a tutorial on data frames to see how to initialize them from various sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the it as key-value pairs where the key will the value of i and r will be it's 2*i.

```
for i in np.arange(0,360): 
    r = 2*i
    df[i] = r
```

If you want you can also combine this dict into your existing dataframe.